# How to send values of Numeric Indicator to Numeric controler in LabVIEW

Tags: controls, labview

I need to get the showing value from **numeric indicator**  and then put that value to the **numeric controller** to show in another numerical indicator in LabVIEW.

Normally we can get the values from numerical control to the numerical indicator.I need the opposite of that.

As shown in picture need a method to get values that show in numerical indicator to the controller.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a Property Node (Value), it has the error lines, so it is useful for dataflow control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local variable or a property node.

**Local Variable**

Right click on the control or indicator, from the shortcut menu choose:

create->local variable

Once you've created that local variable you can right click on it and change it to write or read local.

**Property Node**

Right click on the control or indicator, from the shortcut menu choose:

create->property node->value

You can then right click on the property node and choose 'change to write' or 'change to read'.

**Property Node vs Local Variable**

Either will work in most cases.  Local variables will perform better, providing faster access to the value, similar to that of the control/indicator terminal itself.  Property nodes do provide error terminals that allow for taking advantage of data flow and ordering your operations.  If you already have a property node in use for that control/indicator, adding a value terminal may not impact performance, otherwise use a local, if you need to control order of operations use a flat sequence structure and pass your error cluster through the structure.